# Apache not starting, fails silently/hangs

Tags: apache, debian

I had a web server that got overloaded. I attempted to stop apache but it just hung so I kill -9 the apache pid.

When trying to run

`sudo /etc/init.d.apache2 start`

or any derivative thereof, nothing happens. The command doesn't return. There is no error in log or at command line. I just get `Starting web server: apache2` and the cursor keeps blinking. I've waited 30 minutes and still nothing. The server has 10G of memory free.

I running Debian wheezy.

Comment: What do you mean by "so I kill -9 the apache pid"? Typically apache runs as multi process worker, so killing a single pid will leave processes running...

Comment: I killed the parent process. Apache is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strace showed it was hanging on an nfs4 mountpoint that was not functioning properly.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking at the log files. That should contain the reason.
If there is nothing in the log files, troubleshoot using strace shown here : https://serverfault.com/questions/150249/best-way-to-troubleshoot-apache-not-starting